# Bash: Correct way to Iterate over Map

Tags: bash, dictionary, hashtable, iteration

In Bash I can create a **map** (hashtable) with this common construction

```
hput() {
  eval "$1""$2"='$3'
}

hget() {
  eval echo '${'"$1$2"'#hash}'
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
hput capitals France Paris
hput capitals Spain Madrid
echo "$(hget capitals France)"
```

But how do I best iterate over the entries in the map ?. For instance, in Java I would do:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : capitals.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println("Country " + entry.getKey() + " capital " + entry.getValue());
}
```

is there a common way of accomplishing something similar in Bash ?.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you have bash 4.0 , you can use [associative arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html). else you can make use of  `awk`s associative arrays

Comment: I am on Bash 3 so the awk solution looks far better than rolling my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
for h in ${!capitols*}; do indirect=$capitols$h; echo ${!indirect}; done
```

Here's another:

```
for h in ${!capitols*}; do key=${h#capitols*}; hget capitols $key; done
```

And another:

```
hiter() { 
    for h in $(eval echo '${!'$1'*}')
    do
        key=${h#$1*}
        echo -n "$key "
        hget $1 $key
    done
}
hiter capitols
France Paris
Spain Madrid
```

By the way, "capitol" is a building. A city is referred to as a "capital".

Answer (score 1):

```
hkeys() {
    set | grep -o "^${1}[[:alnum:]]*=" | sed -re "s/^${1}(.*)=/\\1/g"
}
for key in $(hkeys capitols) ; do
    echo $key
done
```

And your hget function is wrong. Try this:

```
hput capitols Smth hash
hget capitols Smth
```

Second command should return the string hash, but it returned nothing. Remove «#hash» string from your function.

Also, `echo "$(hget capitols France)"` is ambigious. You can use `hget capitols France` instead.